# Error when trying to delete in AWS AppSync

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using Graphql within AWS AppSync.  I can create items with no issues but when i try to delete one i get this error.

**ConflictUnhandled - Conflict resolver rejects mutation.**

i am using

```
deleteFavorite(input: {id: "ce8dfa4c-ef87-492e-9a87-f17d2f0b06c8", _version: 1})
```

from this auto created mutation

```
export const deleteFavorite = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation DeleteFavorite(
    $input: DeleteFavoriteInput!
    $condition: ModelFavoriteConditionInput
  ) {
    deleteFavorite(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      productID
      useremail
      userID
      _version
      _deleted
      _lastChangedAt
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to make sure i was passing the same _version back to the delete rewuest